# XMLFormatter dont write xml to file in java

Tags: java, xml, logging

im devaloping a java app that needs to log to an xml file
but after i log to the file it is not in xml format
please help me!!!
 my code:

in main-

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("bankSystemLogger");
```

in bankSystem-

```
try {

            m_fileHandler = new FileHandler("bankSystem.xml");
            logger.addHandler(m_fileHandler);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"msg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage().toString());
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have a look at following example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4114/LogXML-A-XML-Logging-Class

Comment: try to avoid answers like this, because if some time link will broke - your answer will be totally useless.

Comment: im looking for a solution in java the example is in c++. my code should work but i dont why it dosent...